# Spring Boot Boot 3 and JDK 17 - Repositories not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-17

After Updating my Spring Boot Application to ver 3 with updating jdk11 to jdk17
i get following error after starting my application.

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.fx.ln.user.DefaultPermissionService required a bean of type 'com.app.user.repositories.PermissionRepository' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.app.user.repositories.PermissionRepository' in your configuration.

My Repository is looking like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface PermissionRepository extends JpaRepository<PermissionEntity, Long> {
   List<PermissionEntity> findPermissionByUserID(UserEntity userEntityId);
}
```

My Entity like this:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

import java.util.Objects;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "permission")
public class PermissionEntity {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "permission_id", nullable = false)
   long permissionId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
   UserEntity userID;

   @Column(name = "ot_broker_id")
   long otBrockerId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "enq_group_id", referencedColumnName = "enq_group_id", nullable = false)
   EnquiryGroup enquiryGroupId;

   @Column(name = "legal_entity_code")
   String legalEntityCode;

   @Column(name = "access_code")
   String accessCode;

   @Column(name = "access_structure")
   String accessStructure;

   @Column(name = "permission_type")
   long permissionType;

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) {
         return true;
      }
      if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) {
         return false;
      }
      PermissionEntity permission = (PermissionEntity) o;
      return Objects.equals(permissionId, permission.permissionId);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return getClass().hashCode();
   }
}
```

And in my pom.xml i have following dependencies:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

        <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF8</project.build.sourceEncoding>


        <spring-boot-starter-web.version>3.0.5</spring-boot-starter-web.version>
        <spring-webflux.version>6.0.7</spring-webflux.version>
        <spring-security-core.version>6.0.2</spring-security-core.version>
        <spring-security-web.version>6.0.2</spring-security-web.version>


        <springdocopenapi.version>2.0.4</springdocopenapi.version>
        <modelmapper.version>2.4.5</modelmapper.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>
        <git-commit-id-plugin.version>4.9.10</git-commit-id-plugin.version>
        <gson.version>2.9.1</gson.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
         <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
         <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
         <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
         <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
         <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
         <version>${springdocopenapi.version}</version>
      </dependency>

<!--   TEST DEPENDENCIES  -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
         <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
<!--         <version>${junit.version}</version>-->
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${junit.version}</version>-->
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
<!--         <version>${spring-security-core.version}</version>-->
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
         <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
<!--         <version>${mockwebserver.version}</version>-->
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Im also using flyway migration with my scripts in src/main/resources/db/migration
and in my application.yaml i have set

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
    show-sql: true
    open-in-view: true

  datasource:
    url: ${database_url}  # jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1.domain.com:1521/DEV
    username: ${user}
    password: ${password}
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  flyway:
    locations: classpath:db/migration
```

After i have started the application with -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
I see following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/exception/ChangeLogParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:2060) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.findConstructor(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:404) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]


java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationScriptMissingFailureAnalyzer
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]


 TRACE 14020 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.FailureAnalyzers                 : FailureAnalyzer org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.NoDslContextBeanFailureAnalyzer@349f3ff7 failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jooq/DSLContext
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.NoDslContextBeanFailureAnalyzer.analyze(NoDslContextBeanFailureAnalyzer.java:39) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.NoDslContextBeanFailureAnalyzer.analyze(NoDslContextBeanFailureAnalyzer.java:28) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/r2dbc/spi/ConnectionFactory
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.NoConnectionFactoryBeanFailureAnalyzer.analyze(NoConnectionFactoryBeanFailureAnalyzer.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.NoConnectionFactoryBeanFailureAnalyzer.analyze(NoConnectionFactoryBeanFailureAnalyzer.java:34) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
    ... 11 more


org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.user.repositories.PermissionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1824) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1383) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
```

I am realy not sure why this is happening, Everything was working fine before i changed spring boot version and jdk version.

What do I miss?

Any help is much appreciated!

I tried removing flyway migration scripts and package, i changed url of db connection to a false one, upgraded ojdbc version from ojdbc8 to ojdbc11.

I changed all javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence imports.

I tried to enable JPA Repos with enableJPARepositories annotation but it did not work as i would expect, also i did not need to use this previously because my repos where found without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours I found the issue: In the dependency `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` I had added the scope `test`. Removing that fixes the issue and the repositories can be found once again:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
</dependency>
```